# Hypergraph coloring

Tags: probability, graph-theory, hypergraphs

I hawe the following task: Decide if all 4-uniform hypergraph with fourteen hyperedges can be colored with 2 colors.

I think that the answer is yes, but how can i prove it?

Comment: Your intuition is correct, a $4$-uniform hypergraph has to have at least $23$ edges to be non-$2$-colorable (see the [abstract](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X11004975)). The relvant term is the [property B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_B).